# Why does this code with .resize() not work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

The console log works, but the CSS does not change, why?
Also the CSS set on reload works, but not the `.resize()` in connection with the CSS, why?

```
(function(){ 
   var winH = $(window).height(),
       winW = $(window).width()

    $('.frame').css({   
       'width' : winW - 77,
       'height' : winH
    });   

   $(window).resize(function() {
       $('.frame').css({    
           'width' : winW,
           'height' : winH
       });

       console.log(winW);
   });

})();
```

Comment: Show the HTML, and the CSS rules that currently apply to `.frame`.

Comment: Where is the dot-comma after winW = $(window).width() ?

Comment: If I put the dot-comma there, the console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } `.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the height and width within the resize handler so that it will get updated whenever the window is resized

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var winH = $(window).height(),
            winW = $(window).width()
            $('.frame').css({
                'width': winW,
                    'height': winH
            });

        console.log(winW);
    }).resize();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Oh thank you Arun, that was stupid. ;) Shame on me. ;) ;) Now it is working, bless god! Actually the console log was not working either, but updating the same value, thought that would mean the code works, lol. Confused. ;)